# Best way to add asset path variable with React and JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, assets, jsx

What is the best way to add asset path variables?

I am working on an app that has a different asset dir depending on the environment (local, staging, production).

Right now, all my image paths are hard coded in the JSX which works totally fine when developing locally. However, when on staging, the asset path is slightly different.

Here is simple example of what I'm talking about.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="home-container">
            <img className="home-container__logo" src="/images/ui/logos/imagename.png" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The image `src` attribute points to `"/images"`. This may be different in other environments.

Is there a "React way" of adding an asset path var or doing the equivalent of something like `{% static 'images/ui/logos/imagename.png' %}`?

Cheers

Comment: I usually do a function that returns result depending on NODE_ENV and import it everywhere I need, it's pretty simple way

Comment: I'd recommend [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), it comes with built-in methods for handling environment variables and file paths. It's dead simple to get up and running, and helped me a lot with issues like this.

Comment: *"Is there a "React way" of adding an asset path var?"* No. However, webpack is pretty good at this.

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling. Webpack is part of our stack so I will look in to this.

Comment: Have a look at the file loader: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no built in helpers for asset paths in React, but your intuition is good: this is a good abstraction, and worth making yourself. If you're using webpack, you can set the [module resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) to include a path to your root react folder, and then a simple solution might look like this:

```
# app/helpers/AssetHelper.js
export default {
  imagePath: (path) => {
    return `/images/${path}`
  }
}

# your component
import { imagePath } from 'app/helpers/AssetHelper'

render() {
  return (
    <div className="home-container">
      <img className="home-container__logo" src=${imagePath('ui/logos/imagename.png')} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you are not using Webpack or some equivalent, the path will need to be relative, and this won't be such an easy solution. If you're using webpack, check out [module resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/). It will allow you to simplify your imported file paths.

Example webpack config using module resolve:

```
# webpack.config.js
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: ...,
  output: ...,
  resolve: {
    // specify your new path relative to the webpack config file
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './app'), 'node_modules']
  }
}
```